# Page layout broken! What happened?

Tags: magento-1.8, layout

all of a sudden my page layout just completely broke!  I was working on a file in app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml But I don't think it should cause the entire layout of site to break.  Also I re-uploaded a backup I made of that page and it didn't change the site back.  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?  in my error log it says

```
(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found  in /www/sites/www.wishack.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
2014-01-27T21:26:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ye<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  in /www/sites/www.wishack.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
2014-01-27T21:26:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /www/sites/www.wishack.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
```

I checked line 444 in that file and it looks normal...

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Not sure why people are down voting, this is valid. I just ran into the same problem and this helped me.

Comment: Parsing of broken code in layout file causes `line 444` to throw an error. The error isn't in the reported line, but the input that area of code is trying to digest. In this case, the error stack trace is pretty specific at telling you what the input was, though, not what layout file is causing grief. On a *nix system, grep can nail this in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for an xml file that starts with

```
ye<?xml version="1.0"
```

It looks like you have one like this.

Comment: thank you!! I went though and was able to find that file, then clear cache and it's back to normal.  Thank you again!